# Programatically create read-only calendar item for user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following business requirement:

- An automated process needs to create calendar items in multiple end user's O365 calendars
- These calendar items have to be read-only for these users
- They have to be readable/editable/removable by the same automated process

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0), you can't make a calendar item read-only, but you can make a calendar read-only. So I was wondering if I:

- could make a specific calendar for each eligible end-user
- make it read-only for the end user
- how it would be displayed in their outlook/owa

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if you can create a calendar under a user that would be editable, since the user is going to be the owner and the user wouldn’t be able to remove the calendar.

Apart from that, why not [create a calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-calendars) with `"canEdit": false` in the body. That would be a good shot. Let us know if this is the solution.